# Previous pages display after logout and session deleted

Tags: python, django, session

Login code:

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.POST['uname']
        password = request.POST['psw']
        log = User.objects.filter(username=user, password=password)
        if log:
            request.session['login'] = True
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/page')
        else:
            return render(request, 'login.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html')
```

Logout code:

```
del request.session['login']
    request.session.modified = True
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

After logout when I move back I am able to see the previous pages but as soon as I refresh the page it redirects me to login page and restricts me to access previous page.

```
def page(request):
    if not request.session.get('login', False):
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/tnp_admin/")
    else: 
       #access page
```

How to not display previous pages after logout and why is session working only after refreshing page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use `if user.is_authenticated` in the view or import `login_required` property from `django.contrib.auth.decorators` and put `@login_required` on top of your view for that template.